# Surfaceview is not being drawn completely when created initially

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am using `surfaceview` in my android app using following XML code.

```
  <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />
```

The `surfaceview` is supposed to be drawn initially when created and when user touches it. However, when the `surfaceview` is created initially , it is not drawn completely. There exists a small black strip at the bottom of surfaceview. However on subsequent re-drawing, when user touches the surface, it is completely drawn. Why is this issue occuring ?

Answer (score 0):

That issue happens when the layout initially is not covering the entire screen. That can either be a problem in:

- The drawing
- The layout

In this case, I would have to say there is something wrong with the layout. It doesn't cover the screen propperly because of height = 0dp

yes I see the weight, but if you are to make a game it is easier to use FrameLayout and put buttons on top of the canvas.

```
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    />
```

This would have been easier to answer with the full xml layout and the rendering code.